# BigInteger Innacuracy

Tags: vb.net, biginteger

In the following project euler program #56, **Considering natural numbers of the form, a^b, where a, b < 100, what is the maximum digital sum?**

so I wrote the following code:

```
Dim num As System.Numerics.BigInteger
    Dim s As String
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim record As Integer 

    For a = 2 To 99
        For b = 1 To 99

            num = a ^ b
            s = num.ToString

            For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
                sum += CInt(s.Substring(i, 1))
            Next

            sum = 0
        Next
    Next
```

The answer I got from the program was not the correct answer, so I wrote the following code so I can see what numbers set a new high value and see if something is wrong.

```
  If sum > record Then
      record = sum
      Console.WriteLine(a & "," & b)
  End If
```

One of the answers was a=10 b= 81. Obviously that doesn't make sense, because that value is 1 + 81 "0" = 1, but watching the result of 10^81, was `999999999999999921281879895665782741935503249059183851809998224123064148429897728`

I searched about the accuracy of BigInteger but couldn't find anything, is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Try `BigInteger.Pow` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.pow?view=net-6.0#system-numerics-biginteger-pow(system-numerics-biginteger-system-int32 ) instead of `^`. I guess `^` returns a double

Comment: Yes! that was it, Thank you very much!